# How my RAMs are blocked at 2666MHz?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, ramdisk

I would like to get your opinion about my new setup and maybe know why my RAMs are blocked at 2666Mhz and not at 3200.

Here is my setup:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600X Wraith Spire (3.8 GHZ/4.4 GHz)
- ASUS PRIME B450M-A
- CORSAIR VENGEANCE LPX SERIES LOW PROFILE 16Go DDR4 3200MHz CL16
- Seasonic ATX 650W 80+ Gold
- RTX 2070 Super KFA2

After buying all these parts, I decided to build my PC by myself (this is my second hand-built PC).

So, at its first boot, I chose the Profile #1 in the BIOS to put my RAM at 3200MHz. However, when I do this manipulation, it is impossible to reboot the computer and my RAMs are blocked at 3000MHz.

Do you know the reason or has this ever happened to anyone before? Thank you!

Comment: Never start with setting custom RAM timings. First set things to automatic. That should always work and is safe. Customizing may give you a few % speed, but usually doesn't give noticeable benefits. When you go manually adjusting it is not just the clock-speed but all other settings must match the capabilities of your RAM. Some you can set lower or higher, others need to have certain values. Some settings can only be used in specific combinations with other settings. It seems your Profile #1 (whatever that means) picks a combination that isn't valid for the RAM.

Comment: @Tonny While researching some information, I found that changing the slot on the motherboard will allow me to overclock my RAM. I've some grey and black slots on it, I'll try to switch between them. Do you have any information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the slot of my RAMs, the overclocking of them works after it.

Indeed, I move them from the *black slot* to the *grey* one.

Then, on the BIOS, I choose the Profile #1 and it works perfectly!

Here is the slots on the specific motherboard:

[image: H]